# Adobe InDesign: Hidden/non-printing forward slash-markings

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I just came across a (to me) strange phenomena which I can't explain nor find an explanation for via Google. When editing a text, there are some forward slash markings in my text as non-printing characters. Can anyone explain to me what theses are?

[image: Forward Slash]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hidden slash character in InDesign indicates **"End Nested Style Here"**.

`Type > Insert Special Character > Other > End Nested Style Here`

More information on Drop Caps and Nested Styles in InDesign:
https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/drop-caps-nested-styles.html

> You can apply a character style to a specified number of lines in a paragraph. As with nested styles, you can set up two or more nested line styles to work together, and you can create a repeating sequence.
>
> Attributes applied by nested line styles can co-exist with attributes applied by nested styles. For example, a nested line style can apply a color while a nested style can apply italics. If both set conflicting settings of the same attribute, such as red and blue, the nested style takes precedence over the nested line style.

Explanation of InDesign's hidden characters (thanks to @Cai): https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/editing-text.html#view_hidden_nonprinting_characters

Comment: The hidden characters are explained here too: https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/editing-text.html#view_hidden_nonprinting_characters

Comment: Thanks @Cai - added to answer. Don't know why I didn't think to include that :)

Comment: No worries. I did write an answer but you got there first :)